# unique_ptr of a template struct initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, struct, unique-ptr

I have a binary search tree template class, with a struct Node. I am trying to use unique_ptrs of type Node in my tree, but the I cannot get it to initialize

This is my struct

```
template <class T>
struct Node{
    T data;
    unique_ptr<Node<T>> left;
    unique_ptr<Node<T>>  right;
    unique_ptr<Node<T>> parent;
    Node();
    Node(const T & 
    value):data(value),left(nullptr),right(nullptr),parent(nullptr){}
};
```

In my binary search tree class definition I have

```
private:
unique_ptr<Node<T>> root;
```

And then in a function in the bst I have

```
Node<T>* temp(new Node<T>(data)); //works
root(new Node<T>(data)); //does not compile
```

The error message printed out:

```
 error: no match for call to ‘(std::unique_ptr<Node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::default_delete<Node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >) (Node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*)’
     root(new Node<T>(data));
     ^
```

Why is this happening? Any explainations/tips on using unique_ptr would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I have include  and using namespace std at the top of my header file

EDIT:
I have changed it to shared_ptr, as having unique_ptr cannot have both left and right pointing at parent.

I am now using

```
root.reset(new Node<T>());
```

as it was pointed out that I had already constructed root, and did not need to do it again. It seems to be working properly now.

Comment: Have you tried `root = std::make_unique<Node<T>>(data);`?

Comment: Ahh, you are trying to construct `root`, but the object is already constructed, so the compiler thinks you are trying to call `root` like a function. Either initialize `root` in the class member initializer list, or write `root = new Node<T>(data)` (use an assignment operator)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Unrelated, if it isn't obvious, that `unique_ptr` for the *parent* is going to be a sour note when you get to it. The parent is already being pointed to by the `left`, `right`, or the `root` pointer, which are `unique_ptr` as well. thus, the `unique` is disqualified. I suspect you want `shared_ptr` and possible `weak_ptr` for some of this.

Comment: `root.reset(new Node<T>(data));`

Comment: `parent` can just be a raw pointer. Don't be afraid of raw pointer; be afraid of not knowing the scope of the lifetime of your objects.

Comment: Changing it to a `shared_ptr` is unnecessary; you probably shouldn't do that. Just use a raw pointer for your `parent` (or don't have that member). But if you *really* want to use `shared_ptr`, definitely don't have `parent` be a `shared_ptr`, because you'd be guaranteeing a memory leak. I'd personally still use a raw pointer to parent, but you could also use a `weak_ptr`